# SQL match the column's value with all values of other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have only one table: *products*

```
ID | Product Name | Code 1 | Code 2 | Code 3
********************************************
1  |    Phone1    |   MM   |   DD   |  
2  |    Phone2    |   DD   |        |   EE
3  |    Phone3    |   MM   |   ZZ   |   EE
4  |    Phone4    |   XX   |        |
```

I'd like to:

> select all phones which one of their codes match one of the
>   *Phone1*'s code.

In other words:

> if Phone1[Code 1] = Phone2[Code 1] OR Phone1[Code 1] = Phone2[Code 2] OR Phone1[Code 1] = Phone2[Code 3] OR Phone1[Code 1] = Phone3[Code 1] ... etc

Compare each *Phone1 column's value* to each *PhoneX column's value*. 3x3 conditions = 9 in total.

So **it should return**: Phone2 and Phone3 (it should skip matches where empty = empty).

**My attempt** (SELF JOIN) - I'm new to this and can't get this right:

```
SELECT `a.Product Name`
FROM products a, products b
WHERE 
(`a.Code 1` = `b.Code 1`) OR 
(`a.Code 1` = `b.Code 2`) OR   
(`a.Code   1` = `b.Code 3`) OR 
(`a.Code 2` = `b.Code 1`) OR 
(`a.Code 2` = `b.Code 2`) OR 
(`a.Code 2` = `b.Code 3`) OR
(`a.Code 3` = `b.Code 1`) OR
(`a.Code 3` = `b.Code 2`) OR
(`a.Code 3` = `b.Code 3`)
AND `a.Product Name` = "Phone1";
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    Products p
        JOIN Products p1 ON p1.`Product Name` = 'Phone1'
                            AND (p1.`Code 1` IN (p.`Code 1`,p.`Code 2`,p.`Code 3`)
                                 OR p1.`Code 2` IN (p.`Code 1`,p.`Code 2`,p.`Code 3`)
                                 OR p1.`Code 3` IN (p.`Code 1`,p.`Code 2`,p.`Code 3`))
WHERE   p.`Product Name` <> 'Phone1'
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e5ebd/3)

Comment: Besides the somewhat out of place SQL Server syntax, this looks like it could work.

Comment: Thank you! What's the best place in this statement to put something like 'NOT IN' if I want: select all phones which one of their codes match one of the Phone1's code **BUT NOT IF THE CODE = DD**

Answer (score 0):

Should be this query

```
select `a.Product Name` from products as a
left join products as b on  a.`a.Code 1` = `b.Code 2`
left join prodcuts as c on  a.`a.Code 1` = `c.Code 3`
where `a.Product Name` = "Phone1";
```